# Facebook loads page tab secure url as http

Tags: facebook

I'm doing a very basic Facebook app. I have it's "Secure Page Tab URL" set to a SSL certificated URL (https://example.com/). Said URL is nothing fancy, just plain old HTML. I then add the FB app to another FB Page as a tab. Sounds dead simple, right?

No. Instead of loading the contents of https://example.com/, I'm getting a 302 from nginx. According to our server guy, he has it setup so that if someone accesses http://example.com/, nginx will 302 them to https://example.com/. Which leads us to conclude that Facebook is loading http://example.com instead, which makes no sense at all.

I'm pretty sure my Facebook app setup is correct (tested with another site, the iframe loaded with no problems), so the problem must be on our server side. Where should we be looking at? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Not only is it pretty much impossible to answer this (we can only guess without having any info) it's also not programming related.

Comment: A 302 is a temporary redirect (as opposed to a 301, which indicates a permanent redirect). Consider using a 301 and also using the "Strict-Transport-Security" header. These give a very strong indication to load the page over HTTPS. (Facebook might still link to the "http" page... but the use of "Strict-Transport-Security" will ensure that users load the HTTPS page automatically without the redirect after the first visit).

Comment: (It's a little unclear what you're asking, though; for example, is this just a regular website that you are testing to see what happens when shared/loaded in the Facebook app? Or some other integration?)

Comment: Yeah there are programming related (/s) integrations after I can get the app to work correctly. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: _“Which leads us to conclude that Facebook is loading `http://example.com` instead, which makes no sense at all”_ – that is highly unlikely. Much more likely, that this is your site’s fault. Use your browser’s developer tools (network panel) to see what is really going on – pretty sure that Facebook will request the HTTPS version, but then your site messes it up by redirecting back to HTTP somehow.

Comment: I did admit it must be our fault, I just need to know where to look (network is not my forte). Will fiddle through firebug for more clues.